# what's the difference between cautious and wary?

Tags: word-usage

Collins dictionary says:

> If you are wary of something or someone, you are cautious because you do not know much about them and you believe they may be dangerous or cause problems.

I found some examples in dictionaries.

> 1. Brands need to be cautious about which environment they place
>      themselves in.
> 2. They were very wary about giving him a contract

What would be the difference between **wary (of/about)** and **cautious (about)**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting question. The two words are synonymous for the most part. However, *wary* has a bit more of an emotional component in it, a feeling of reluctance to do whatever one might be wary about doing. *Cautious* is more of a carefulness based on reason.

From [the Merriam-Webster definition of *cautious*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cautious) (the synonym discussion halfway down the page):

> *Cautious* implies the exercise of forethought usually prompted by fear of danger. ⟨a cautious driver⟩ ... *wary* emphasizes suspiciousness and alertness in watching for danger and cunning in escaping it.